# npm-search - display only name and description columns in the results

Tags: javascript, json, npm

When I search for a package using `npm search packagename`, the results are displayed in 6 columns: name, description, author, date, version and keywords. How can I make npm-search display only name and description columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the name and description are the first two fields, this works for me in bash:

```
npm --silent search -l --color -p packagename | cut -f -2
```